# D.py/rewrite - Confessions System

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I made a confessions system but there’s some things that are wrong with it. How would I make it so when users want to type, they don’t have to put in *confess and they can just type whatever they want without needing to use a command? And how do I make a mod logs channel to log the deleted confessions with the author name, etc.?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Confess(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: discord.ext.commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def confess(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, message: str):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649868314869760)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Success", description=f"I've received your confession and sent it to the <#806649874379964487> channel!")
        embed.set_footer(text="Confessions")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649874379964487)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Confession", description=f"{message}")
        embed.set_footer(text="All confessions are anonymous.")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Confess(client))
```

Comment: Look into `wait_for`, and for the mod logs channel you can just use `get_channel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question** 
If you want to use a "command" without actually using a command you could make an `on_message` event, check the id of the channel (like a confessions channel) and if it matches then do the thing

Example:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == some_channel_id_here:
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649868314869760)
        await message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Success", description=f"I've received your confession and sent it to the <#806649874379964487> channel!")
        embed.set_footer(text="Confessions")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649874379964487)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Confession", description=f"{message}")
        embed.set_footer(text="All confessions are anonymous.")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

**For the second question** 
You can use `get_channel` again to get the log channel and post in there. (If you mean't on how to check if someone deleted a message/confession, use [on_message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete))

Example:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def confess(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, message: str):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649868314869760)
        log_channel = self.client.get_channel(log_channel_id)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Success", description=f"I've received your confession and sent it to the <#806649874379964487> channel!")
        embed.set_footer(text="Confessions")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(806649874379964487)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Confession", description=f"{message}")
        embed.set_footer(text="All confessions are anonymous.")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await logchannel.send("User confessed something!")
```

Comment: How would I get the message id of the confessions for the mod logs?

Comment: ctx.message.id if you use ctx as an argument, if you use message then message.id